# Find following Element which matches class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help with the following task: I have the following HTML.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 tileinfo"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 tileinfo"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 tileinfo"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfoliotile"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12 tileinfo"></div>
</div>
```

All Elements with class `.portfoliotile` are clickable elements. I need a solution to get the following element with class `.tileinfo`

I've tried it with

```
$(this).closest('.tileinfo').addClass('active');
```

`this` represents the clicked .portfoliotile-Element but I think I'm on the wrong way...

Comment: Did you edited your question? I ask it because all these unrelevant answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nextAll('.tileinfo:first')` to get the following first element which has the class `tileinfo`.

```
 $(this).nextAll('.tileinfo:first').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Yep, this did it! Thanks

Comment: It will add the active class always to the first div having class tileinfo.Not to the last div

Comment: Not the first but first after the clicked `.portfoliotile` and this is what OP needs. @shu

Comment: Because your solution will always active first `.tileinfo` in the parent `.row`  not the first `.tileinfo` after clicked `.portfoliotile`. By the I didn't down vote. @shu

Answer (score 0):

Use `closest` to get parent div and `find` to get descendants having class tileinfo

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.tileinfo').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).siblings('.tileinfo').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score -1):

use `next`

```
$('.portfoliotile').click(function(){
$(this).next('.tileinfo').addClass('active');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1n2ye3t1/

Comment: Your solutions works only if the d is a direct sibling, or?